# Javascript object sum values of same property key

Tags: javascript

I Have the following object and I want to sum the values of the same ingredients name, like: tomato: 5, chicken:5, rice: 1, peas: 1, i have this code but is not making the sum, instead is showing all the objects

```
var data3 = {
  "menus": [{
    "recipe": "chicken with rice",
    "ingredients": [{
      "name": "tomato",
      "value": 2
    }, {
      "name": "chicken",
      "value": 3
    }, {
      "name": "rice",
      "value": 1
    }]
  }, {
    "recipe": "Garden rice",
    "ingredients": [{
      "name": "tomato",
      "value": 3
    }, {
      "name": "chicken",
      "value": 2
    }, {
      "name": "peas",
      "value": 1
    }]
  }]
};

var ingredients;

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  ingredients = data3.menus[i].ingredients;

  var temp = {};
  var obj = null;
  for (var j = 0; j < ingredients.length; j++) {
    obj = ingredients[j];

    if (!temp[obj.name]) {
      temp[obj.name] = obj;
    } else {
      temp[obj.name].value += obj.value;
    }

  }
  var result = [];
  for (var prop in temp)
     result.push(temp[prop]);

  console.log(result);

};
```

I will appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: The `+= obj.value` line is the one where you are summing the values IF the object already exists in the temporary object. However, every time you iterate over the recipes in the main object, your `temp` object is replaced with a new object, `{}`. 
Try moving the `temp` variable to initialize it when you initialize your `ingredients` variable, and you should end up with an object with the sum of the value for each object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a hash table with the name of the ingredient and use a default value of zero if a property does not exist. Then add the value.

```js
var data3 = { menus: [{ recipe: "chicken with rice", ingredients: [{ name: "tomato", value: 2 }, { name: "chicken", value: 3 }, { name: "rice", value: 1 }] }, { recipe: "Garden rice", ingredients: [{ name: "tomato", value: 3 }, { name: "chicken", value: 2 }, { name: "peas", value: 1 }] }] },
    ingredients = Object.create(null);

data3.menus.forEach(function (a) {
    a.ingredients.forEach(function (b) {
        ingredients[b.name] = (ingredients[b.name] || 0) + b.value;
    });
});

console.log(ingredients);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is correct, just you were re-initializing temp again and again. So you just need to take temp out of your for loop.

```
var data3 = {
  "menus": [{
    "recipe": "chicken with rice",
    "ingredients": [{
      "name": "tomato",
      "value": 2
    }, {
      "name": "chicken",
      "value": 3
    }, {
      "name": "rice",
      "value": 1
    }]
  }, {
    "recipe": "Garden rice",
    "ingredients": [{
      "name": "tomato",
      "value": 3
    }, {
      "name": "chicken",
      "value": 2
    }, {
      "name": "peas",
      "value": 1
    }]
  }]
};

var ingredients;
var temp = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data3.menus.length; i++) {
  ingredients = data3.menus[i].ingredients;

  var obj = null;
  for (var j = 0; j < ingredients.length; j++) {
    obj = ingredients[j];


    if (!temp[obj.name]) {
      temp[obj.name] = obj;
    } else {
      temp[obj.name].value += obj.value;
    }
  }
};

var result = [];
  for (var prop in temp)
     result.push(temp[prop]);
  console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that will traverse all ingredients and if `ingredient.name` has given name, then add `ingredient.value` to your result. Here is ES2015 solution with arrow functions:

```
const sumIngredients = (menus, name) => {
  let result = 0;
  menus.forEach(meal => {
    meal.ingredients.forEach(ingredient => {
      if (ingredient.name === name) {
        result += ingredient.value;
      }
    })
  })
  return result;
}
```

The use it:

```
sumIngredients(data3.menus, 'chicken'); //5
sumIngredients(data3.menus, 'tomato'); //5 
sumIngredients(data3.menus, 'rice'); //1
sumIngredients(data3.menus, 'peas'); //1
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/sc8wrupk/